# How do I minus 5 minutes from a UNIX TimeStamp? (Sorted)

Tags: javascript, time

The question is rather self explanatory, I'm wanting to work 5 minutes behind on my script, and I'm working via Unix timestamps.

For instance if I have my log at "1709586485691" what would I need to subtract to go back 5 minutes.

Thank you for any help!

Edit : Sorted thank you! Sorry I've never used the timestamps before

Comment: Subtract 5 * 60 from it. How could this not be obvious?

Comment: 5 * 60 * 1000?  I think you need to account for ms/s

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamps are expressed in second. The timestamp you shared is *not* a unix timestamp, because it uses milliseconds.

This means to subtract 5 minutes, you need to subtract `5*60*1000 = 300000` milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you! I've never had to do this before, so learning as I go. I needed a StackOverflow account soon enough anyways. Got it working just fine now!

Comment: @DarthRevan good luck, and hope it was helpful!